# Anchor without href

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best crossbrowser way to make anchor without href (javascript-driven) behave like real anchor? The most obvious one is to use # as anchor but it makes page jump...

Comment: Behave as an anchor in what sense?  Having the cursor and underlined on mouse-over?  If so it would be better to do things through CSS.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A do-nothing link, that doesn't even jump:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
```

**Update:** As linked document suggests (pointed out by Ambrosia), since `void(0)` returns `undefined`, it is better to actually write above code as:

```
<a href="javascript:undefined">link</a>
```

Unless, of course, undefined has been re-defined.

Comment: This is not what the void method is intended for. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

Answer (score 9):

These will not jump:

```
​<a href="#null">Click</a>
​<a href="#n">Click</a>
<a href="#undefined">Click</a>​
```

They are, however, soul destroying and extremely ugly.

Answer (score 7):

You should **return false** from the click handler associated to the anchor. Given the HTML:

```
<a id="example" href="/whatever"/>
```

the JS should look like:

```
document.getElementById('example').onclick = customAnchorReturn;
function customAnchorReturn() {
    // do stuff
    return false;
}
```

or using jQuery:

```
$('a#example').click(function(){
    // do stuff
    return false;
});
```

In this way, the JS will be unobtrusive and in case JS is disabled the anchor will still work.

Answer (score 4):

If you're reacting to the click event, just make sure you return false and whatever is in the href, whether a #hash or other url, will be ignored.

```
<a href="#anything" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is OK too:

```
<a href="javascript:;">link</a>
```